# Metro config not accepting blockList

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I am building a react-native app with expo, I am using the modules of react-native-svg-transformer and also amplify (where I have created functions). The problem is that the functions in the amplify directory have package.json files and do not work. This is why I'm trying to put the amplify directory in the blocList of the metro configuration, but I keep getting the error:

`Failed to construct transformer:  TypeError: Transformer is not a constructor`

This is my metro config:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config")

// extra config is needed to enable `react-native-svg-transformer`
module.exports = (async () => {
    const {
        resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
    } = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname)
    return {
        transformer: {
            babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
            assetPlugins: ["expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles"],
        },
        resolver: {
            assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
            sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
            blockList: [/amplify.*/]
        },
    }
})()
```

I also tried this but it didn't work either:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config")

// extra config is needed to enable `react-native-svg-transformer`
module.exports = (async () => {
    const {
        resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
    } = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname)
    return {
        transformer: {
            babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
            experimentalImportSupport: false,
            inlineRequires: true,
        },
        resolver: {
            assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
            sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
            blockList: [/amplify.*/]
        },
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

It was that some packages used metro-config@0.59 and I npm-installed metro-config@0.61 so they were incompatible.